# How to return data from an Autocomplete component

Tags: javascript

I need to filter the data, lets say that the user types in *A*, so in `<p>{this.state.result}</p>` I want to print everything with the letter *A*. By everything, I mean the heads of the `object`, in this case `Travel` and `Gambling` contains *A*.

this is the data that I need to iterate

```
const falsyData = [{
    'Hello': {
      'what I do'       : 'you just say Hello',
      'which language'  : 'english'
    },
    'Travel': {
      'Etymology' : 'The origin of the word "travel" is...',
      'Purpose'   : 'include recreation'
    },
    'Gambling': {
      'Gamble'  : 'Gambling is the wagering of money...',
      'Origins' : 'Many popular games played in...'
    }
  }];

  render () {
    return (
      <Grid>
            <TextField
                onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                onKeyUp={this._changeInput.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.value} />
            {!!this.state.value.length &&
              <Row>
                <Column>  
                 //HERE I PRINT THE RESULTS OF THE SEARCH
                  <p>{this.state.result}</p>
                </Column>                              
              </Row>
            }
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  _matchData = (input) => {
    let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return falsyData.map(function(data) {
      if (data.match(reg)) {
        return data;
      }
    });
  }

  _changeInput = (val) => {
    let autoCompleteResult = this._matchData(this.state.value);
    if (autoCompleteResult.length) {
      this.setState({result: autoCompleteResult.join(' ')});
    };
  }

  _onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

the way I am doing it, I am getting an error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: data.match is not a function

Comment: You are missing some code. person.match is not part of the code you provided.

Comment: @RichardGrant so sorry, it was `data`

Comment: data is not defined in your code.

Comment: @RichardGrant look at the code, `data` comes from here `return falsyData.map(function(data)...`